# Instance vs Prototype Methods for AngularJS Controllers in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

If I don't intend to inherit my controller class, is there any difference between defining an AngularJS Controller's methods as prototype methods over instance methods?

Coming from a C# background, I'm more comfortable with defining prototype methods. I also like keeping the constructor short.

However, most examples I see for AngularJS define methods at the instance level.

```
module Test {
    angular
        .module("app")
        .controller("controller",
        ["$scope", MyController]);

    export class MyController {

        public Function1: () => {}

        constructor(private $scope: IMyScope) {
            //instance
            this.Function1() = () => {
                alert("Hello 1!");
            }
        }
    }

    //prototype
    public Function2(): void {
        alert("Hello 2!");
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I don't intend to inherit my controller class, is there any difference between defining an AngularJS Controller's methods as prototype methods over instance methods?

Instance methods come with a performance impact. Other than that it's perfectly fine to use them. I just use prototype members.

This video explains why you might want to use instance methods : https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA (mainly to capture this)